# Wake Ubuntu from suspend

Tags: suspend

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
It is working fine in all ways except I need to wake it from sleep with a wireless mouse or keyboard so I can use Ubuntu on my multi media PC. Don't want the mouse and keyboard cables accross the floor.
I have applied the solutions (in terminal) suggested online but it does not enable wake from suspend with wired or wireless devices.
I have been using various distros for years but I would rate myself as a newbie as I haven't needed to get into any serious terminal use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question?? [How to exit from suspend mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/1490557/1450948)